# Object of class NSThread autoreleased with no pool in place

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I am working on multi-threading using the following codes in XCode4:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

bool trigger = false;
NSLock  *theLock=[NSLock new];

@interface Metronome : NSObject
+(void)tick:(id)param;
@end

@implementation Metronome
+(void)tick:(id)param{
while(1)
   {
           NSLog(@"TICK\n");
           usleep(1000000);
           [theLock lock];
           trigger = true;
           [theLock unlock];
   }
}
@end

int main()
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(tick:)
toTarget:[Metronome class] withObject:nil];
}
```

There is no compiling error, but during execution the console pops up the following warning:

```
objc[688]: Object 0x100300ff0 of class NSThread autoreleased with no pool
in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

I'm not familiar with the memory management of obj-C. Can someone explain this to me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a [NSAutoreleasePool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsautoreleasepool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for every thread that need invoke `autorelease` include main thread

```
int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(tick:)
toTarget:[Metronome class] withObject:nil];
    [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need a thread pool.

```
-(void)someMethod {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //code that should be run in the new thread goes here

    [pool release];
}
```

You could also considering using arc.
http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/